# The Rosenberg diary and the functionalist-intentionalist debate

Tags: world-war-two, historiography, holocaust

Today it was [announced](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/history-of-nazi-germany-to-be-revised-as-diaries-of-hitler-confidante-alfred-rosenberg-are-tracked-down-in-us-8652696.html) that the diary of Alfred Rosenberg was been found, after it had disappeared in 1946.

Prima facie, this would seem to be a major piece of historical evidence for the [Functionalist vs. Intentionalist debate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functionalism_versus_intentionalism). What puzzles me at this stage is this: the news article says the diary was entered as evidence in the Nuremberg Trials; this means that parts of it might have been available for historians as part of the trials' documentation.

If so - what part has the diary played so far in the debate?

Comment: Rosenberg's diaries aren't available in the [Nuremberg Trials Project](http://nuremberg.law.harvard.edu/php/docs_swi.php?DI=1&text=overview), the only documents attributed to Rosenberg are either letters or extracts from interrogations. Of course that might just mean the trial documents that related to the diaries just haven't been digitized (yet?), but there goes our best chance of reading them for ourselves.